# How can I group view results based on the week of the year using a date field?

Tags: views, datetime

I have a list of events (custom content type *event*) shown in a view.

There are several events each week.  Each event has a **date** field, *date*, that records the date that the event will be held.

I would like to group the events by the week of the year that they occur.  For example:

- Next week
- Two weeks from now
- Three weeks from now
- Four weeks from now

Is there a fancy way to compute the week using the date field and views grouping?

Comment: There is this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74970/how-to-list-nodes-and-have-them-grouped-by-day-week-month

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without using a PHP field (or similar). Those modules are usually bad practice to put PHP into the database like that.

You can create a date format in Drupal for 'Week'.  Then you add the date field to the View and use this week format.  That will output the value of the date as a week #.  Then you group on that value.

A views filter can also help restrict the view to now + 4 weeks.  And some views theming can make each week header be whatever you need it to be.